# Python google-cloud-bigquery Parquet column 'Date' has type INT64 which does not match the target cpp_type INT32

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery

I am trying to upload a Dataframe to a BigQuery Table using `client.load_table_from_dataframe`. And I am also supplying a schema using the

```
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
    schema=[xxxxxx,xxxxxx,xxxxxx])
```

All of this have worked untill I had to move the code to a new Virtual Machine and install all the packages again. I have been googeling this a bit and it seems like more people have had problems with Parquet and BQ where they have solved it by installing packages again. This does not seem to work for me.

And I also dont understand why the error says that the Date is a `INT64`. In pandas it is a `Datetime[n64]` type. And in the BQ table and schema it is a DATE type. Is there anyone who have had similar problems with this?

Comment: I have this same issue - I think this may have to do with how bigquery is treating date columns between different versions of bigquery. I'll post again if I find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably cast your date as a string in the dataframe before loading it in:

```py
df["date"] = df["date"].map(lambda x: x.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")) 
df["date"] = df["date"].astype(str)
```